# Pure-FTPD chroot not working on a fresh Debian install?

Tags: debian, ftp, chroot, pureftpd

I am trying to get chroot to work with virtual Pure-FTPD users, but for some reason it simply is not working.

I changed the following options:

**/etc/default/pure-ftpd-common:**

```
VIRTUALCHROOT=true
```

**/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone:**

```
yes
```

And added a virtual user with a homedirectory, which shows like this:

```
Login              : <someuser>
Password           : <foo>
UID                : 1003 (ftpuser)
GID                : 1003 (ftpgroup)
Directory          : /home/<homedir>/./
```

***What am I missing here?***

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is not working?  Is the user able to login but just not chrooted?

Comment: @pablo that is exactly the case as mentioned in the title. Login works, chroot does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Turned out my FTP server was running through inetd instead of standalone.

**When configured in inetd mode, the conf dir seems to be ignored.**

Answer (score 2):

Try set VIRTUALCHROOT=false and "/./" from user home dir.

/etc/default/pure-ftpd-common:

```
VIRTUALCHROOT=false
```

cat /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone:

```
yes
```

When restart, exist -A option:

> /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
>   Restarting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l pam -O clf:/var/log/pure->ftpd/transfer.log -u 1000 -E **-A** -8 UTF-8 -B

/etc/passwd:

```
test:x:1001:1001::/home/test:/bin/sh
```

Chroot work:

```
# ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 11:03. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (localhost:ooshro): test
331 User test OK. Password required
Password:
230-User test has group access to:  test      
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 40034
226-Options: -l 
226 0 matches total
```

Comment: Tried this already and does not work. The init.d script outputs nothing, by the way.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0X98ayID1k